# Integrity constraint violation - 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, laravel, constraints

I'm facing a problem with a many-to-many relationship when I try to save data into the intermediate table. Basically, a client HAS MANY observations, and I have `tbl_cients`, `clients_hasmany_observations`, and `tbl_clients_observations`.

Foreign Keys into migrations:

```php
Schema::connection('dev')->table('clients_hasMany_observations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('client_id')->on('tbl_clients');
    $table->foreign('observation_id')->references('observation_id')->on('tbl_clients_observations');
});
```

Clients Model:

```php
/**
 * The observations that belong to the client.
 */
public function observations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ClientsObservations', 'clients_hasmany_observations', 'client_id', 'observation_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Observations Model:

```php
/**
 * The observations that belong to the client.
 */
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Clients', 'clients_hasmany_observations', 'client_id', 'observation_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Taking this, if I try to add a new client and attach a dummy observation, I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`helderne_dev`.`clients_hasmany_observations`, CONSTRAINT `clients_hasmany_observations_observation_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`observation_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_clients_observations` (`observati) (SQL: insert into`clients_hasmany_observations`(`client_id`,`created_at`,`observation_id`,`updated_at`) values (4, 2020-04-15 11:05:09, 50, 2020-04-15 11:05:09))```

I can't really understand why because I added the keys. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT #1
In the controler I'm writing:

```php
$new_client = Clients::create($request->all());
$new_client->observations()->attach([50]);
dd($new_client);
```

50 would be the possible ID of the observation in the tbl_clients_observations.

Answer (score 0):

The attach method doesn't accept an array (unlike the similar sync method).  See [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) for reference.

Try the following:

```
$new_client->observations()->attach(50);
```

Comment: No, I deleted the FK creation in the migration files. Ans the script runs OK. So, I will advance in the projects and do more tests after...

Answer (score 0):

Disable the foreign key checks before saving your data to your table

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
```

Then re-enable it

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
```

This will solve the problem

Comment: This actually works, but doesn't feel that this has to be done to the app work...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but according to the docs, "The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');"

So I think you may have the foreign keys switched on the clients function. Not sure if it will solve all problems, but try switching them:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Clients', 'clients_hasmany_observations', 'observation_id', 'client_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```